# Android: Attribute name has invalid character ' '

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest

I am creating an app that uses multiple  tags. So i am getting these 3 errors when i run my app. These errors just appeared out of nowhere -

```
Error:(14) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.

Error:(14) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

When i hover-over the red marked text on the manifest file i get this error

```
 `“URI is not Registered”?`
```

Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name="com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide.SecondActivity"
            android:label="Second Activity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide.addlocation" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide.About"
            android:label="About" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide.about" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide.Websites"
            android:label="Websites" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide.navigate" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.android.ict.seneca.androidpocketguide.SingleListItem"
            android:label="Single Item Selected" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: this mean extra unwanted spaces

Comment: i am sorry, i got it. Its here : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Answer (score 0):

just delete the space in the last permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

to :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```